# heightForRowAtIndexPath is not resizing cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` and I'm using a prototype made in Storyboard. The prototype cell has a height of 270, and the tableview row height is also set at 270. My delegate and datasource are all set up properly, because the cells are rendering.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    SLSCase* currentCase = [_cases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(!currentCase.hasReport){
        return 71;
    }

    return 270;
}
```

In the above delegate method, I'm checking from my datasource, for what size the cell should be, and the conditionals are working. (eg. if `currentCase.hasReport`, then the height will be full)

However, in the app, the cell is still showing as full size. The difference is that all interaction is gone, I can't tap it or anything, but I can still see the entire cell.

I've tried disabling AutoLayout as well.

Comment: perhaps you could show us your TableViewController class

Comment: Make sure you checked *custom* checkbox in **Size Inspector**

Comment: Also check for `User Interaction Enabled` checkbox checked. and property **identifier** and also make sure that you didn't use any `UITapGestureRecognizer` because it's just overlap any user interaction, and check for _hasReport_ boolean value comes true or not